# "standardize = " option in glmnet package

Tags: r, scale, glmnet, lasso-regression, standardization

I have one question regarding the standardize option in a glmnet package. 
I understand that scaling or standardizing dataset is necessary for the regression analysis in order to make the coefficients meaningful. 
Usually, for just a linear regression (e.g., using a glm functionin R), I manually scale the dataset using a scale() function before I run the glm model. 
However, it seems that, when it comes to using a glmnet package (for a regularized regression), a standardize option does standardize the dataset, thereby making the coefficients meaningful (comparable) by itself. Am I correct?

If this is correct, suppose that I run the following code. And it turns out that the variable "x3" has the highest coefficient (in an absolute value scale). Then can I conclude that **the variable "x3" is the most important variable in discriminating the categories**???

I am looking forward to hearing any opinions!! Thanks.

```
set.seed(12345) 
example.dat <- data.frame(Category = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
                          x1 = rpois(100, 10),
                          x2 = rnorm(100, 3, 10),
                          x3 = rbeta(100, 8, 20),
                          x4 = rnorm(100, -3, 45),
                          x5 = rnorm(100, 1000, 10000))

sample = sample.split(example.dat$Category, SplitRatio = .70)
train = subset(example.dat, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(example.dat, sample == FALSE)

set.seed(12345)
lasso.fit <- cv.glmnet(data.matrix(train[,-1]),
                       train[,1], 
                       family         = "binomial",
                       nfolds         = nrow(train), # LOOCV
                       grouped        = FALSE,
                       type.measure   = "class",
                       alpha          = 0.6,
                       standardize    = TRUE,
                       standardize.response = TRUE)
print(lasso.fit)
coef       <- as.matrix(abs(coef(lasso.fit, s = "lambda.1se")))
coef.order <- as.matrix(coef[order(coef, decreasing = TRUE),])
rownames(as.matrix(coef.order[coef.order[,1]>0,]))
# [1] "x3"          "(Intercept)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of late response, but hope it helps.

Keep in mind when using the native standarization option that `glmnet` returns the coefficients on the original scale (see below from the docs), so I would be careful about drawing that conclusion.

Whenever I want to compare coefficients on the same scale, I use `scale()` to standardize before running `glmnet`. That way, you can get scaled coefficients returned for your comparisons.

> standardize
> Logical flag for x variable standardization, prior to fitting the model sequence. The coefficients are always returned on the original scale. Default is standardize=TRUE. If variables are in the same units already, you might not wish to standardize.

[glmnet documentation](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/glmnet.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Colin H . If I use scale() before running glmnet, then is it right that I need to set standardize = FALSE in order to get standardized coefficients for comparison?

Comment: Exactly, there is no need to standardize if you've already done so manually before you input the data into the model. That said, and I haven't tested it personally, but the standardize option shouldn't make much difference if you've already scaled your data.